# web page is unable to load from assets folder

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

I am trying to draw one HTML file using WebView.But it is showing **Web Page not available** error.
[image: error]
please help me to resolve the issue.

**about.java**

```
package kc.RajusLabs.iamhere;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class About extends Activity {

    WebView about;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);
      //full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        about = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WVAbout);
        about.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/about.html");


    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is **android_asset** remove extra s from assets and here you go.

Comment: It's working fine now .Folder name is assets but we are  using asset why?

Comment: Its how android read folder structure, nothing much we can do. :) I'm glad it worked for you. Please mark my post as accepted answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
about.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about.html");
```

Loading file from assets required `file:///` not `file://`.

Comment: still getting same problem

Comment: @KCRaju Double check your file name

Comment: even i tried with single character as file name.but no use :(